# Differentiability of $f(x)$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions, absolute-value

> If $f(x)=a_0\cos|x|+a_1\sin|x|+a_2|x|^3$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then
>
> (A) $a_1=0, a_2=0$
>
> (B) $a_0=0, a_1=0$
>
> (C) $a_1=0$
>
> (D) $a_0, a_1, a_2$ can take any real value

The differentiability of $f(x)$ is due to the individual contribution of each of the terms making up $f(x)$ . The graph of $\cos|x|$ does not have any corner. The graph of $\sin|x|$ has a corner at $x=0$. So $a_1$ has to be $0$. Now, my problem starts here. The graph of $|x|^3$ does not have any corner. It is smooth although a little flat near $x=0$. But the graph of it's derivative has a hole at $x=0$. Therefore it is not differentiable at $x=0$. Thus $a_2$ is also $0$. My question is why does the graph of the derivative of $|x|^3$ have a hole at $x=0$ inspite of the fact that the graph of $|x|^3$ has no corners?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto |x|^3$ is differentiable at $x=0$. Clearly $\lim_{x \to 0} {|x|^3 \over x} = 0$. $\cos |x| = \cos x$ near $x=0$. What do you mean by the 'graph has a hole'?

Comment: @copper.hat, the derivative of $|x|^3$ is $3|x|^2\times \frac{x}{|x|}$.

Comment: Only for $x \neq 0$, for $x=0$ the derivative is $0$ as I have shown.

Comment: The definition is $f'(x) = \lim_{y \to x} {f(y)-f(x) \over y-x}$. My first comment shows that $f'(0) = 0$ for this particular $f$. Generally, if $|f(x)| \le c|x|^2$ then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0) = 0$. Just from the definition.

Comment: I cannot understand "Clearly $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|x|^3}{x}=0$".

Comment: If $x \ne 0$ then $| { |x|^3 \over x} | = |x|^2$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} |x|^2 = 0$. You might want to review your limits.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, let's find the derivative of $|x|^3$.

$f(x)=|x|^3$

$f(x)=x^2|x|$

By the product rule (and by remembering the derivative of $|x|$),

$f'(x)= 2x|x|+\frac{x^3}{|x|}$

We can further simplify:

$f'(x)=\frac{2x|x|^2+x^3}{|x|}$

$f'(x)=\frac{2x^3+x^3}{|x|}$

$f'(x)=\frac{3x^3}{|x|}$

$f'(x)=3x|x|$

Now we can just evaluate this limit to check for continuity.

$\lim_{x\to0}3x|x|=0$

It helps to simplify the derivative; however, if you left it as a fraction, it would be indeterminate at 0-- not undefined.